# Stemming french text with NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stemming

I'm trying to stemming a text in French with NLTK

> europe amérique nord fruits espèce fraisier bois petite taille connus depuis antiquité romains consommaient utilisaient produits cosmétiques raison odeur agréable cultivée jardins européens
>
> fraisier musqué connu fruits petits saveur musquée unique connaisseurs donnent supérieur fraise jardins cultivé depuis siècle premier cultivar connu genre appartient espèce chapiron nommé 1576
>
> fraisier vert cultivé fruits moins appréciés fait acidité plus forte espèces fait objet cueillette consommation personnelle
>
> siècle explorateur rapporte plants fraisier espèce intéresse assez fruits parfumés cultivée commerce jours existe production industrielle faible suivie première fraise mûrir

I'm trying to follow the NLTK tutorial, but it's not working.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import FrenchStemmer

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

   stemmer = FrenchStemmer()
   tokens = word_tokenize(file)
   french_stem = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in word_tokenize(file)]
   stemmed_text = ' '.join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in word_tokenize(file)])
   print(stemmed_text)
```

**output:**

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: could not reproduce... the code works fine, when I do it. Is this the code that you used? In your given code is a IndentationError. `stemmer...` and all lines below need to match the indentation level of `file...`

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Can you please let us know on which line the error is thrown?

Comment: I'm very stupid, it works perfectly. I'm sorry!